# What is most pythonic way to check if multiple dictionary keys match

Tags: python

Suppose I have a dictionary `my_dict`.

What is the most pythonic way to check if `my_dict['a'] == 'b' and my_dict['c'] == 'd' and my_dict['e'] == 'f'`?

I do not want it to throw any exception if the keys `a`, `c` or `e` don't exist in `my_dict`

Comment: "I do not want it to throw any exception if the keys a, c or e don't exist in my_dict" What should happen instead?

Comment: "Most Pythonic" is opinion-based, and thus off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can form a tuple with Map and compare it.  By Mapping the get method, missing keys will produce a None value and not crash.

```
(*map(my_dic.get,('a','c','e'),) == ('b','f','d')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zip values and keys together and use `get()` in a generator expression passed to `all`:

```
my_dict = {'a':'b', 'c':'d','e':'f'}

keys = ['a', 'c', 'e']
vals = ['b', 'd', 'f']

all(my_dict.get(k) == v for k, v in zip(keys, vals))
# true
```

This assumes values are not `None`, since `get()` returns `None` for missing values. If that's important, you can check for inclusion as well.

This will be `False` when keys are missing  or values are different like:

```
my_dict = {'c':'d','e':'f'}

keys = ['a', 'c', 'e']
vals = ['b', 'd', 'f']

all(my_dict.get(k) == v for k, v in zip(keys, vals))
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very simple use case, where the desired values have near identical character codes to the keys, you can use `ord` to get the numeric code point or ordinal for a single-character string, and `chr` to convert it back to a single-character string.

Note that the code point of `b` is one higher than `a`, for example.

```py
>>> my_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
>>> keys = ['a', 'c', 'e']
>>> all(my_dict.get(k) == chr(ord(k) + 1) for k in keys)
True
```

A similar approach using `map`, adapted from the answer above:

```py
>>> list(map(my_dict.get, keys)) == [chr(ord(k) + 1) for k in keys]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide most understand-friendly and simple code at my opinion:

```py
if my_dict.get('a') == 'b' and my_dict.get('c') == 'd' and my_dict.get('e') == 'f':
  print('all keys exist and values are correct')
else:
  print('one of keys is not exist or value of at least one key is not correct')
```

`my_dict.get(key_name)` return `None` if `key_name` not exist. `b`, `d` and `f` are not `None`.

[About get method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

Also you can catch error:

```py
try:
  if my_dict['a'] == 'b' and my_dict['c'] == 'd' and my_dict['e'] == 'f':
    print('all keys exist and values are correct')
  else:
    print('all keys exist but some of values are not correct')
except KeyError:
  print('some of keys are not exist')
```

It is so basic but... I guess it is should be here because it basic